# Administer Users permission too vague. How can I restrict functionality for this permission?

Tags: users

Is there a way to allow some admin users (with administer role) to create other users but limit their access to 'people' related admin area? It seems there's only one option under permissions - Administer users - which seems to dictate either full package (create all different profile2 users, access admin people list view etc) or nothing.

I have a 'sales person' role on the system. This user has to be able to create other profile2 based users but not to access user configuration or even general listing (not to mention that depending on number of profile2 profiles, multiple Add People links appear)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Role Delegation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module does what you need to do. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows site administrators to grant some roles the authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the administer permissions permission.
>
> For each role, Role Delegation provides a new assign ROLE role permission to allow the assignment of that role.
>
> The module also adds an assign all roles permission. Enabling this permission for a role is a convenient way to allow the assignment of any other role without having to check all the assign ROLE role permissions in the Permissions page.
>
> If an administrator has the administer users permission, a role assignment widget gets displayed in the account creation or editing form, and bulk add/remove role operations become available on the user administration page. Otherwise, if s/he has at least the access user profiles permission, the module adds its own Roles tab to the user profile so that roles can be assigned.

Comment: It's not what I need actually. This module seems to deal with roles assignment. I want to be able to allow a specific user role to create other users (essentially just access this url admin/people/p2rp-create/user). And only this. Everything else, admin user view, other Add People links (as there could be a few depending on number of profile2 entities), user configuration has to be disabled